# SQL view - result different than select

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, pivot, sql-view

I got table `users_movies` like this:

```
ID (100 records) | movie_id | ranks ( 0 or 1)
-----------------+----------+----------------
     1           |   3      |   0
     2           |   2      |   0
     3           |   2      |   1
     4           |   3      |   0
     5           |   1      |   1
     6           |   2      |   0
     etc.
```

My SQL is:

```
SELECT
    movie_id as Movie,
    (SELECT COUNT(ranks) 
     FROM users_movies
     WHERE ranks = 1 AND movie_id = Movie) AS plus,
    (SELECT COUNT(ranks)
     FROM users_movies
     WHERE ranks = 0 AND movie_id = Movie) AS minus 
FROM 
    users_movies
GROUP BY 
    movie_id
ORDER BY 
    movie_id
```

and result table is, as expected:

```
Movie | plus | minus
------+------+------
  1   |  5   |   2
  2   |  3   |   3
  3   |  0   |  10
  etc.
```

But when I want to create view:

```
CREATE VIEW v1 
AS /*the only line I add */
    SELECT
        movie_id as Movie,
        (SELECT COUNT(ranks) 
         FROM users_movies
         WHERE ranks = 1 AND movie_id = Movie) AS plus,
        (SELECT COUNT(ranks)
         FROM users_movies
         WHERE ranks = 0 AND movie_id = Movie) AS minus 
    FROM 
        users_movies
    GROUP BY 
        movie_id
    ORDER BY 
        movie_id
```

the result is completelly different:

```
Movie | plus | minus
------+------+------
  1   |  45  |  55
  2   |  45  |  55
  3   |  45  |  55
  etc.
```

What causes this and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aliased the table and used qualified column names inside the correlated subqueries then you would get correct results:

```
CREATE VIEW v1 AS    
SELECT
        um.movie_id as Movie,
        (SELECT COUNT(ranks) 
        FROM users_movies
        WHERE ranks = 1 and movie_id = um.movie_id) as plus,
        (SELECT COUNT(ranks)
        FROM users_movies
        WHERE ranks = 0 and movie_id = um.movie_id) as minus 
FROM users_movies um
GROUP BY um.movie_id
ORDER BY um.movie_id;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qncfJdgpyzwLxHcF7xmAn5/0).
Of course there is a better way to meet your requirement with conditional aggregation and MySql offers easy and readable solutions like:

```
CREATE VIEW v1 AS
SELECT
    movie_id,
    SUM(ranks = 1) plus,
    SUM(ranks = 0) minus 
FROM users_movies
GROUP BY movie_id;
```

This code would work for any values of the `ranks` column representing *plus* or *minus* ranking.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qncfJdgpyzwLxHcF7xmAn5/1).

Answer (score 2):

Your original query mixes aggregation and subqueries that do not seem properly correlated.

You can simplify it with conditional aggregation:

```
create view v1 as
select
    movie_id,
    sum(ranks) plus,
    count(*) - sum(ranks) minus 
from users_movies
group by movie_id
```

This works because `ranks` is 0 or 1, so `sum(ranks)` gives you the number of records where `rank = 1`, and `count(*) - sum(ranks)` gives you the count of 0s.

If values are others than 0 and 1, then the technique is a it different:

```
create view v1 as
select
    movie_id,
    sum(case when ranks = 'good' then 1 else 0 end) good,
    sum(case when ranks = 'bad' then 1 else 0 end) bad 
from users_movies
group by movie_id
```

Comment: Oh, seems I was late with my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is happening. Two things that I see:

- You are creating an alias `Movie` in the select clause. You should not be able to use this alias in the same select clause, as there is no order in which parts of the select clause must be eveluated.
- In the subqueries you use the movie ID from the main query. There is no aggregation on the subquery result (such as `MIN`, `SUM` or the like), so this must be the unique movie ID after the main query's aggregation. Or is this MySQL? Then this becomes quirky, as MySQL allows to omit the aggregation function. Still, even this doesn't explain different results.

After all, you only want this:

```
CREATE VIEW v1 AS
SELECT
  movie_id,
  SUM(ranks) as plus,
  COUNT(*) - SUM(ranks) as minus
FROM users_movies
GROUP BY movie_id;
```